# How can I compare visibility Android Tic-tac-toe

Tags: android, visibility, tic-tac-toe

Hey I need help I'm trying to do the game Tic Tac Toe but i have a problem with a "if" sentence.

It's when 3 circles are visibles and now i want to make the line visible but the code don´t work.

```
if (
    cir9.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE &&
    cir8.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE &&
    cir7.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE
) {
    linea_horizontal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: show the `Circle` class & the error stack trace, if you get any error.

Answer (score 0):

What about to use [`isShown()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isShown%28%29) method?

```
if (cir7.isShown() && cir8.isShown() && cir9.isShown()) {
   // make your work
}
else {
  // are not visible
}
```

Comment: nop neither, and there isn't an error.
I try with the code of Sajmon and when I put isShown==false appears the line but when it's true don't appears it

Comment: 'if(cir9.isShown()==false)
 {
  linea_horizontal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }'